# Chat search results don't list anything after June 15 2016

Tags: bug, chat, search

I have tried searching a bunch of common terms in two chat rooms, and the results are never more recent than June 15 2016. The test was in The Render Farm, part of Blender.SE, and Moonwards, part of Space.SE, with no user name specified. Just noticed this morning, it would seem some glitch has crept in.

Comment: Yes. Searching "movie" in the Screening Room gives the last date of June 15th, 2016 as well... This seems to only be affecting the main chat servers. Chat.meta is fine: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=language&user=&room=89 as is SO: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=where&room=139

Comment: this was at 2012 a couple of hours ago then 2014. I suspect they are updating/rebuilding the index/cache.

Comment: Looks fine to me; searching [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=SmokeDetector&user=&room=11540) seems to show posts dated today.

Comment: It's happening again: https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=test&room=11540 (last result: January 2016). On reload, more results appear, so it might be a caching issue or something?!